# Can I set UILocalnotification to repeat every last day of every month?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I want to try this myself, but it would take a month before I can sure it work. Any one have ever try this ?

```
NSDate *fireDate = // Date I want to repeat, in this case 31 may 

localNotification.fireDate = fireDate;
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSMonthCalendarUnit;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

I expected it to alert on the last day of every month. Is this a way to go ? And if I schedule it on 30-day month and the next day is 31-day month like April -> May What should I do, because I can only set it to 30 April (also February 28 and 29 day problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got an answer after playing with `UILocalNotification` for a while, If you want to make it repeat every last day every months just set it to January 31 with `repeatInterval` `NSMonthCalendarUnit` and it will repeat every last day of every months